# Powershell script doesnt recognize variable

Tags: powershell

My script goes like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\dist" -recurse -Include *.msi | ForEach { 
    Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList  "/i $_.Fullname  /qb"
}
```

I try to find the msi file with wildcard and install it. But script seems that doesnt recognize the variable $_.Fullname
If i execute this script like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\dist" -recurse -Include *.msi | ForEach { 
   msiexec.exe /I $_.Fullname  /qb
}
```

It works but it runs it asynchronously because it misses Wait parameter and if I add - Wait there the script fails.

Can anyone tell me how to run this script with wild card and synchronously

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out, by removing .Fullname from the variable like this: 
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\dist" -recurse -Include *.msi | ForEach { 
 Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList  "/i $_  /qb"
}

Comment: Use subexpression `"/i $($_.Fullname)  /qb"` or give the arguments as array

Comment: As aside, `-Filter *.msi` would be much faster than `-Include *.msi`